# Invalid format. Wrong parameters passed error in windows cmd with curl

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

I am new to curl, trying to upload some media using rest api, I am using windows 10 64 bit, installed curl and trying to run curl statement on cmd, getting the error of invalid paremeters, my curl statement attached bellow:

```
curl -u "tayyabnasir1:ZbbQhE5oSvVEBLh2bjqA" -X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app- 
automate/upload-media" -F "file=/tr.jpeg" -F 'data={"custom_id":"MyMedia"}'
```

and next I am attaching the error message :

```
{"error":"Invalid format. Wrong parameters passed. Refer to REST API document for valid API format - 
https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/rest-api"}
```